# In multidc cassandra cluster dc's showing eachother as DN

Tags: cassandra, connection, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

I have 8 nodes in my cassandra cluster which has two datacenters with 4 nodes each. I am using cassandra version 2.0.9 in all nodes. For the last 10 days there are some connection disturbances occurred. But it had resolved immediately. But nodes in DC1 can't handshake with nodes in DC2. The message shown as

```
INFO [HANDSHAKE-/172.21.142.249] 2016-06-08 15:19:23,022 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 386) Handshaking version with /172.21.142.249
INFO [HANDSHAKE-/172.21.142.249] 2014-06-08 15:19:23,024 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 406) Cannot handshake version with /172.21.142.249
```

In `nodetool status` also shows as down.
If i run `nodetool status` from DC1 nodes it shows all DC2 nodes are down.
If i run `nodetool status` from DC2 nodes it shows all DC1 nodes are down.
But both are showing `nodetool gossipinfo` as normal and some heartbeat value.

After i restart one node from DC2, then i run `nodetool status` it shows that node and DC1 nodes as UN, others DC2 nodes as DN. Afer i restarted all the nodes from DC2, it's working fine. But can't understand the rootcause of that issue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What gossip protocol are you using?

Comment: @gsteiner i don't understand your question. did you mean snitch? if it is i'm using PropertyFileSnitch

Comment: Yes, I meant snitch.  Sorry about that.